# Style thumbnail titles on mobile with Squarespace

Tags: css, mobile, squarespace

I'm trying to style the titles on the mobile device to match what I have displayed on a narrow desktop view. See images

```
warface.co.uk
pass:squared
```

**Desktop Chrome / Narrow view** (Desired view)

[image: Chrome / narrow view]

**Mobile view Chrome / iOS**

- Title to sit in the center of the view
- Remove unwanted black opacity background

[image: Mobile view]

Comment: it will be better if you create a snippet for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'Toggle device mode' in Chrome to simulate the iPhone view.

And the line I was looking for is

```
    html.touch #grid .item a div.wrapper { }
```